# Iphone 5 is refusing to turn on

Tags: iphone, hardware

I've read earlier that after completely recharging iPhone 5 it should automatically turn on. But only in case when battery was drained to 0% and phone turned itself off.

I have recharged the phone to 100% but it is refusing to turn on. My power button is not working. Are there any other means to switch it on?

Answer (score 1):

If an iPhone or iOS device doesn’t self start after 15 minutes of charging, the proper step is to force a reset and then repeat this pattern four or more times before seeking a repair of the hardware.

Since your home button is broken, you could try disconnecting from power and reconnecting at each 15 minute point and hope.

You likely have two problems that need fixing, though. The button and the power circuitry or the electronics to start / run are failing. The tech (or you) will need to open the device to figure out which.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to turn it on pressing the power button and home button at the same time once it's charged?

Comment: Like  I said earlier, my power button is not working